# Powershell remove files older than x days

Tags: powershell

Goal is to remove files older than x days. For testing using copy.
Found more than a few posts on how to do this - however the problem I'm experiencing is that regardless of the property used with the variable and the comparison ALL files are moved (copied). Secondly trying to pipe the results to a log file will create the file but not write to it. I'm missing something but can't see it. Any input on what I am doing wrong is appreciated!

```
$SDirectory = "C:\TestOne*"
$Destpath = "C:\TestTwo"
$limit = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-2)
$Full = Get-childitem -path $SDirectory -Recurse -Include *.bak,*.trn

foreach ($i in $Full) 
{
    ##if ($i.CreationTime -gt ($(Get-Date).adddays(-2)))
    if ($i.LastWriteTimeUtc -gt $limit)
    {
      Copy-Item -Path $Full -Destination $Destpath -Force | Out-File C:\Admin\Results11.txt -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using $Full instead of $i.Fullname in the copy, and what result do you expect from copy?

Comment: copy of course, didn't see till now I was telling it to copy everything.

Comment: But aside from doing it's job copy has no output you could append anywhere as long you omit the -passthru option and thats ugly like dir.

Comment: Works when you append `-passthru |select -ExpandProperty Fullname |Out-File .\Results11.txt -Append` HTH

Answer (score 1):

The reason all files are being copied is because you actually copying them:

```
Copy-Item -Path $Full ...
```

I think you want something more like this:

```
Copy-Item -Path $($i.FullName) ...
```

To capture the output use `-PassThru`:

```
Copy-Item -Path $($i.FullName) -Destination $Destpath -PassThru -Force | Out-File C:\Admin\Results11.txt -Append
```

Comment: You also want to make sure to use -lt rather than -gt if you are trying to copy the files that are older than x days rater than newer than x days

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I see what I did wrong assuming the for-each would handle it.

Comment: i dont knew -passthru    really pratics, ty

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
$SDirectory = "C:\TestOne*"
$Destpath = "C:\TestTwo"
$limit = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-2)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$SDirectory" | % {
    if ($_.CreationTime -gt $limit) {
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName "$Destpath"
    Add-Content "C:\Admin\Results11.txt" -Value $_.Name
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, as Mike Garuccio said, you may use either -lt or -gt depending on the result you need.